# Binding parameters to query without knowing names in advance

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jdbi

I have queries that have named parameters however I only have the argument available meaning I don't know the names of the parameters and the number of times they appear in the query.

Using `JDBI`, `JDBC` or maybe other tools, what is the best approach in such a situation? Is there anything that can autobind arguments in order?

Comment: What do you mean with "only have the argument available"? Would you like to create prepared database statements without knowing the columns used as predicates in the queries?

Comment: Named parameters makes it sound like you are using JPA (e.g. Hibernate). Are you?

Comment: An example might help us understand. Sounds like you have a query string e.g. `SELECT * FROM user WHERE first_name=:firstname` and you don't know ahead of time what named parameters are in it? And you want to bind values to those parameters?

Comment: Let's say I received a query like `select * from user where first_name = :label and last_name = :label` and need to bind the parameter `joe` to it. I don't know ahead of time how many `:label` will be or if it is going to be called `:label` at all

Comment: I receive queries that I need to execute with given parameters and export the results to excel sheets so that's the main problem.

Comment: Maybe support for [StringTemplate in JDBI](http://jdbi.org/#_stringtemplate_4) may help you out...